# Configuration "Content-Disposition header" in "Apache HTTP Server"

Tags: java, apache, aem

I make a request to generate an XML file. Which then should be displayed in the browser. But if the XML file is cached, it is downloaded. I solved this problem by creating a filter that will change the header. But this option does not fit. I know that can customize "Apache HTTP Server".

```java
@Component
@SlingServletFilter(
        scope = {SlingServletFilterScope.REQUEST},
        extensions = {"xml"}
)
public class StaticFilesFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String CONTENT_DISPOSITION_HEADER = "Content-Disposition";
    private static final String CONTENT_DISPOSITION_HEADER_VALUE_INLINE = "inline";

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        //Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        final SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = (SlingHttpServletRequest) request;
        final SlingHttpServletResponse slingResponse = (SlingHttpServletResponse) response;

        slingResponse.setHeader(CONTENT_DISPOSITION_HEADER, CONTENT_DISPOSITION_HEADER_VALUE_INLINE);
        filterChain.doFilter(slingRequest, slingResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //Do nothing
    }

}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I dont understand what your question is. the filter doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the problem correctly the problem is in caching itself.

The XML file is probably cached on dispatcher and then served from cache without the 'Content-Disposition' header. To solve this you need to tweak your dispatcher configuration. There are at least few ways, here are two of them:

1. Cache 'Content-Disposition' header on dispatcher
       /cache
       {
           /headers
           {
              "Content-Disposition"
           }
2. Hardcode the rules on apache, for every XML request in specific location add the header using mod_headers https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html